# Произвел или выполнил?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно сказать?

> Произвел проверку сопротивления изоляции.

или

> Выполнил проверку сопротивления изоляции.

Answer (score 2):

*Оба* варианта возможны, оба они формальны (в отличие от простого "проверил сопротивление изоляции") но второй *более* формален: он характерен для случая исполнения обязанности, действия по указанию или следования инструкции.